# FtpWebRequest - Issue with the MSDN example

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

I'm trying to understand the MSDN documentation for FtpWebRequest and more specificaly, [how to upload using FTP and C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms229715.aspx)

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace Examples.System.Net
{
    public class WebRequestGetExample
    {
        public static void Main ()
        {
            // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.contoso.com/test.htm");
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

            // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("anonymous","janeDoe@contoso.com");

            // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
            StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader("testfile.txt");
            byte [] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
            sourceStream.Close();
            request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

            response.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the code above they reference 2 file types. Am I right in assuming that testfile.txt is the 'source' file (on the local computer) and test.htm is what testfile.txt will be renamed too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - you're uploading *to* `test.htm`, loading the data *from* `testfile.txt`. You can tell that because `test.htm` is part of the URL (so is remote) whereas `testfile.txt` is loaded by just creating a `StreamReader` over a file.

(It's worth noting that this code is pretty bad in various ways, by the way - particularly around resource disposal. Don't treat it as embodying best practices...)

Comment: Hi Jon. Yeah, you've explained to me in the past about "using" (as does your book)! So, using the above code, could I change the destination to: www.domain.com/myFile.zip? The example is confusing as it's an FTP (a web uri) and saving a file as a file type associated with the web!

Comment: @DaveRook: Yes, you could... although that would be odd, as I really wouldn't expect a text file to also be a valid zip file (whereas it could reasonably be an HTML file). Normally I'd expect you to keep the same file extension though...

Comment: Yes, that's fine, my source already is a .gz file and so will the destination! Perfect, again, thanks for taking the time.

Comment: @DaveRook: Right - in that case one thing to make *absolutely* sure of is that you don't use `StreamReader`, which will treat it as a text file.

Comment: Crumbs, that is exactly what I've been doing, no wonder if complains about the file type! Well, this saves me from having to post another question, thank you!